# Using group by left join and count using linq

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I am using LINQ to fetch the record from the database, I have written a SQL query in SQL server for which I am writing LINQ query in asp .net MVC, I'm using group by left join and count in the query so it says it does not have range variable in the select, I have tried a lot of things but failed, following are the queries

Sql query:

```
select Post_ID, Post, com.cmtcount  from Posts left join (select Comments.postID,
 Count(Comments.comments) as cmtcount from Comments group by postID)
 as com on com.postID = Post_ID;
```

Linq query:

```
from row in db.Posts join cmtrow in db.Comments on row.Post_ID
 equals cmtrow.postID into ps from cmtrow in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
  group cmtrow by cmtrow.Comments_ID into grouped  select new 
{ row.Post1, row.Posted_by,cmtrow.comments,
 count = grouped.Count(t=>t.Comments_ID!=null) };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
      p.Post_ID
    , p.Post
    , COUNT(c.CommentID) as cmtcount
FROM Posts p
    LEFT JOIN Comments c ON c.PostID = p.Post_ID
GROUP BY p.Post_ID, p.Post
```

In LinQ, you could write something like this:

```
from p in db.Posts
join c in db.Comments on p.Post_ID equals c.PostID into commentsInPost
select new
{
    PostId = p.Post_ID,
    Post = p.Post1,
    cmtcount = commentsInPost.Count()
};
```

The SQL generated by LinQ is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Post_ID] AS [Post_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Post] AS [Post], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Post_ID] = [Extent2].[PostID]) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
```

Both SQL syntax are correct and will return the same result, it is up to you to decide which one to use.